# #C, program that you input gross pay and get net income

Tags: c

I need help with writing a program that asks the user for his gross pay and than later gives him his net pay or net income. If the gross pay is less than 204000 then that indudivial is taxes at 30% and anything above 204000 is 50%.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    //Declaring and initializing variabless
    double income, tax;
    char quit = ' ';

    //Loop for multiple oparations
    while (quit != 'q' && quit != 'Q') {

        //Getting input from the user
        printf("\n\n\nInput your annual income:\t");
        scanf("%lf", &income);

        }

         if (income <= 204000) {
            tax = (income - 250000) * 30 / 100;                 
        }

        else if (income >= 204000) {
            tax = (income - 650000) * 50 / 100;         
        }


        //Giving the output
        printf("\n\n\nYour tax is:\t%0.2lf Taka\n\n\n", tax);

        //Getting out of the loop
        getchar();
        printf("Input Q or q to exit. Input any other character to continue: ");
        scanf("%c", &quit);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The code does not work and I am not getting the tax rates I should have, 30% for less than 204000 and 50% for more than 204000

Comment: The code is simpe enough to run it by hand. Get pen&paper and follow **exactly** the code as you wrote it - don't skip a step, no matter how obvious it looks. One thing: `if … else if … else` tests should always be mutually exclusive, your's is not (you alo don't need to test for the negated condition, just use `else`).

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind this line please ? `tax = (income - 650000) * 50 / 100 + 40000;  `

Comment: sure, the 40000 is an error, but the 65000 was an idea from my friend, he recomended that.

Comment: Read [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @maker: This is what we call "magic numbers". They do not have a name, so they do not have meaning. By assigning them to variables, at the very top of your program, you GIVE them names, which hopefully explain what they are for and where they are from. If the name is not enough, add a comment for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should google "tax brackets" to get a better understanding of how to calculate taxes.

When you earn less than, or equal to 204000 you pay 30% taxes:

```
tax = income * 30.0 / 100.0;
```

If not, you pay 30% tax on the first 204000, and 50% tax on the rest:

```
tax = 204000.0 * 30.0 / 100.0
      + (income - 204000.0) * 50.0 / 100.0;
```

**Important Tip:**

When you want the result of your calculations to be `double` or `float` it is often important to prevent the use of integer arithmetic. For instance if you write

```
tax = (30 / 100) * income;
```

then, since both 30 and 100 are integers, the program will calculate 30/100 using integer division, which results in 0 and not 0.33333... To force floating point division, you must make sure that one (or both) operands are floating point.

Like this:

```
/* 30.0 is a float  */
tax = (30.0 / 100) * income;
```

... or this:

```
/* 100.0 is a float */
tax = (30 / 100.0) * income;
```

... or even this

```
/* income is a double which makes (income * 30) a double */
tax = income * 30 / 100;
```

... or have all operands as floats or doubles:

```
tax = income * 30.0 / 100.0;
```